# Random layered non-overlapping scatter plot in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, plot, data-visualization, scatter-plot

I am plotting (for example three) different datasets using `scatter` or `plot` with the `hold on` function consecutively. This generates a scatter plot with the last layer overlapping with all the other ones.
Is there a (plotting) function that can randomly disperse the layers?

Comment: I would like that the first layer of scatter is not fully overlapped with the last layer. Ideally, dots should appear randomly in first or last layer. Something like here: http://www.cell.com/cms/attachment/2061927522/2063377357/gr2_lrg.jpg

Comment: Provide a [MCVE]  of your problem that explains how it is different from the desired result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way you could achieve this is via a 3d plot.

Create a depth vector of the same length as your x & y vector with random numbers and plot using plot3 (instead of plot).

You can then use the command view(2) to change the viewpoint you will get the effect you are after.

**Example**

```
f1=figure;
f2=figure;
nValues = 2000;
for dataSet=1:3
    r1 = rand(nValues,1);    
    r2 = rand(nValues,1);    
    r3 = rand(nValues,1);
    t = r1 * pi * 2;
    x = r2 .* cos(t) + r1(1);
    y = r2 .* sin(t) + r2(1);
    depth = r3;
    set(0,'CurrentFigure',f1)
    plot(x,y,'.', 'MarkerSize',25)    
    hold all

    set(0,'CurrentFigure',f2)
    plot3(x,y,depth,'.', 'MarkerSize',25)    
    hold all
end
% Change viewpoint 
view(2)
```

**Data plotted with plot command (distinct layers)**
[image: Distinct Layers]

**Data plotted with plot3 command using a random value for z (depth)**
[image: Random Depth]